# browser.driver.currentUrl() timing out in protractor tests for angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumber

So i am doing an e2e using protractor and selenium for an angular 2 app, where i have a download button, which opens two new tabs. My test is to check that two new tabs are opened and each tab has one specific value in the url. Both the tabs are opened simultaneously.

```
Then('the title plan opens in a new tab', function (callback: any) {
     console.log('inside then');
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        const newWindowHandle = handles[1];
        console.log(newWindowHandle);
        browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function (){
            console.log('inside switch');
            chai.expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.have.string('PBL1899_AUTO_TEST_TP').and.notify(callback);
        });
    });
});

Then('the title sheet opens in a new tab', function (callback: any) {
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        const newWindowHandle = handles[2];
        browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function (){
            console.log('inside switch');
            chai.expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.have.string('PBL1899_AUTO_TEST_TS').and.notify(callback);
        });
    });
});
```

The first 'then' condition works fine and passes. During the second 'then', the control switches correctly to the other tab, which is already loaded, but it waits indefinitely at ***browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()***.

If i reverse the then condtions, then too, whichever is executed first works fine, but the second one goes on an indefinite wait. What is happening here?

Funnily though, during this wait period, if i press manual refresh(F5), then the wait ends and the test completes successfully, otherwise it times out.

I even tried introducing an auto_refresh, by using the code:

```
browser.driver.navigate().refresh()
```

But that too went on a wait without actually refreshing the window. Is there something with the **browser.driver**??. I checked and it seems that all the browser.driver methods are on wait.

Any help?? I am really stuck around here. Thanks.

**EDIT:** *So found out that this is happening only if the tabs contain something that is loaded pretty fast. In my case, the tabs where just giving some simple html without any load time, as this was a test.* 
*But when i ran in an SIT server, where the tabs were loading heavy web pages, this worked fine, as during the tab switch, that particular tab would still be loading and test would complete successfully.*